# sql selection of one value from several identical

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the result of executing a query. it collects data from several tables. he is such a:

```
|Name|date       |number|Id 
|alex|01-01-2021 |1111  | 1
|mike|01-01-2021 |2222  | 2
|alex|02-01-2021 |1111  | 3
|alex|03-01-2021 |1111  | 4
|john|04-01-2021 |3333  | 5
```

i need to get the following result:

```
|Name|date      |number| Id 
|mike|01-01-2021|2222  | 2
|alex|any value |1111  | Any value
|john|04-01-2021|3333  | 5
```

I need to select one of the repeated values and show it.I have a large query with many columns. here I gave only a short version to explain the essence of the problem

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: use group by name,number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this CTE and manage which date (first or last) you will get

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT
  Name, 
  date, 
  number,
  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY date) AS row_num
FROM test01
)
SELECT 
  Name, 
  date, 
  number
FROM data
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Name,max(date) as date,number
from atable
group by Name, number
```